# uninitialized constant UsersController when trying to ban user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I get this error when I'm trying to ban user, hope you can help me, thanks

> ActionController::RoutingError at /users/1/banned
>
> uninitialized constant UsersController

views/admin/index.html.erb

```
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <p>  
     <%= user.email %> 
     <%= link_to "ban user", banned_user_path(user) %>
     </p> 
  <% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
  devise_for :users do
    resources :users do 
      member do 
        get :banned
        post :banned
      end
    end
  end
```

controllers/admin_controller.rb

```
  def banned
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    session[:return_to] ||= request.referer
    @user.update_attributes(banned: true)
    redirect_to session.delete(:return_to)
  end
```

Comment: It seems that this `banned` method should belong in the users controller. You've told us that it is in `controllers/admin_controller.rb`. In saying that you can then have your view "code" in `views/index.html.erb`

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you don't have a UsersController. Create a UsersController and put your `banned` function in there. You can create a UsersController in the command line with `rails g controller Users`